# Specifying account info when calling Azure createServiceBusService

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

### Background

I am creating a basic Node.js app that uses Azure's Service Bus, but I can't find a way to properly send my configurations to the methods because I can't find any documentation for Node.js.

### Research

I have read this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-queues#create-a-queue

In that tutorial they have the following quote:

> The Azure module reads the environment variable
>   AZURE_SERVICEBUS_CONNECTION_STRING to obtain information required to
>   connect to Service Bus. **If this environment variable is not set, you
>   must specify the account information when calling
>   createServiceBusService**.

I can't set an ENV variable for this ( for various reasons ) but I can send my account information to the method when calling it.

Problem? There is no information anywhere specifying how that should be done with Node.js.

I have also searched all the documentation I could find, but it is usually in C# or Java.

### Code

Following is a sample code that illustrates the issue:

```
const azure = require( "azure" );
// Pass account information object to this method
const serviceBusService = azure.createServiceBusService( );
```

### Questions

1. What is the input format expected by the method `createServiceBusService`?
2. Is there any document describing the Azure Service Bus API for Node.js?

Comment: Please try something like: `const serviceBusService = azure.createServiceBusService('Endpoint=sb://<service bus account name>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<your shared access key>');`

Comment: Jesus .. it worked! I was expecting the method to receive a JSON object of some sort or anything *else*. How did you know it was just the string? Where did you find that info? If you write it down I will accept it as the answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a connection string to the method:

```
const serviceBusService = azure.createServiceBusService('Endpoint=sb://<service bus account name>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<your shared access key>');
```

Unfortunately documentation is pretty bad for Service Bus but the good thing is that the SDK is open source on Github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/tree/master/lib/services/serviceBus. You can use the source code in lieu of documentation.

In fact, I found this solution from there only (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/serviceBus/lib/servicebusservice.js#L61).

Comment: Using source code instead of documentation is so wrong in so many ways ... But you did a great job. Thanks for the help!